# how to make Facebook Login Button's onlogin call a function not in window object

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In what context is the onlogin callback called?

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="my_callback">
```

It seems that Facebook Login Button's `onlogin` callback will only work if the callback is a property of the `window`, i.e.

```
window.my_callback = function() { MY_APP.my_callback(); }
```

Is it possible to make this work, for example:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="MY_APP.my_callback">
```

so I can stop cluttering my `window` with `my_callback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `()`:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="MY_APP.my_callback()">
```

and I don't know why it works :)